# How to obtain a subarray in python 3

Tags: python, list

I want to get a subarray in python 3. I have tried the following.

```
a = ['abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh' , 'abcdefgh']

print (a[0][3:6])
print (a[1][2:6])

print  (a[0:2][3:6])
```

I get the first two results as expected. But I am not able to obtain the desired result for the 3rd print statement.

Output :

```
def
cdef
[]
```

Desired Output :

```
def
cdef
['def', 'def']
```

Can anyone tell me how to obtain it

Comment: `[x[3:6] for x in a[:2]]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use list comprehension for this

```
print ([i[3:6] for i in a[0:2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work. It will iterate over elements at index 0 and 1 and will slice the array as expected.

```
[x[3:6] for x in a[0:2]]
```